# Клик по кнопке в WebBrowser

Tags: html, delphi, webbrowser

Как кликнуть по кнопке на сайте через Delphi WebBrowser?

```
<li class="rating__up " id="up_r" data-rating="up">
    <i class="i-rating_up"></i>
</li>
```

Пробовал это сделать с помощью `getelementbyid` и по `classname`.

Если вручную кликнуть по кнопке в браузере, то ничего не выходит, потому что IE не поддерживает различные скрипты. А автоматически не выходит.

Что сделать, чтобы заработало?

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо в реестре прописать ваше приложение ([статья](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version), вас в этой статье интересует только в какую ветвь, что необходимо записать), чтобы оно использовало последний движок IE и уже после этого нажать кнопку в ручную, но если и после этого не происходит нажатия, остается только вариант - использовать движок другого браузера

Comment: Если нужно, вот готовый код на C++ чтобы включить последнюю версию IE
https://github.com/zenden2k/image-uploader/blob/1.3.2/Source/Func/WinUtils.cpp#L998